# Favorites disappeared from dock

Tags: dock, dconf, favorites

I'm running Ubuntu 21.10.
Everything was fine until I went to add the trash icon to the dock in dconf editor and it removed all of my favorites from the dock. Also the trash icon never appeared on the dock. I tried turning the favorites off and on, the trash of and on, and a few other options in dconf and never could get my favorites, trash, and running programs to return to the dock.
Is there anyway to get the favorites back?

Comment: I tried using the command  $ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-favorites true and still no success

Comment: Add all useful information to your question itself: use "edit". Comments may not be read or may disappear.

Comment: You can use the [dash to dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension or someother extensions which are same as ubuntu dock. FYI:Ubuntu default dock is based on dash to dock, You can easily configure it to look like ubuntu dock or even better

Answer (score 2):

Reset all Ubuntu dock settings to the factory default of Ubuntu 21.10 with the following command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock
```

This will reset all to the default, which includes a trash icon on the dock. You now can add your own favorites and remove the ones you do not want.

Comment: still did not work

Comment: Temporarily create a new account, see if the problem also happens there.

Comment: the problem goes away in the new account and remains on the original account. is there a way to fix the original account?

Answer (score 2):

Set *apply-custom-theme* **true**

This worked for me if you have other extensions enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Following  worked for me

1. Open Dconf Editor
2. Set show favorites to false
3. Again set show favorites to true